# OnGUI Unity2D Обновление

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть счётчик жизни и я бы хотел в OnGUI, но почему-то после касания не обновляется OnGUI, и возможно сделать более красивым OnGUI.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class hero : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool IsGround;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    int jump_study = 0;
    int Life = 100;

    void Start()
    {
         jump_study = 0; 
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (jump_study < 2))
        {
            jump();
            anim.SetInteger("Temp", 3);
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0)
        {
            anim.SetInteger("Temp", 1);
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            Flip();
            anim.SetInteger("Temp", 2);
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            //Invoke("ReloadLevel", 2);
            Life--;
        }
        else
        {
            jump_study = 0; 
        }

    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 30), "Life - " + Life);
    }
    void ReloadLevel()
    {     
        Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene.name);
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        float euler = (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 ? 180f : 0);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, euler, 0);
        //transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 ? 180f : 0), 0);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 5f, rb.velocity.y);
        rb.velocity = movement;
    }
    void jump()
    {

        rb.AddForce(transform.up * 4f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        jump_study++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Оно само пофиксилось, но другой вопрос, как более красиво сделать это всё.

Comment: Вы используете старую, **очень** старую систему GUI. По сути, она до сих пор существует только ради обратной совместимости. Попробуйте перейти на [Unity UI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.ugui.html). Это современная система, помимо прочего - она визуальная, т.е. с ней можно работать прямо в редакторе.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, GUI сделать более красивым нельзя. Там стандартные прямоугольники и надписи. К тому же GUI работает медленно (хотя при небольшом его использовании это незаметно).
Советую всё же не лениться и использовать настоящий UI Canvas, с TextMeshPro. Он для этого и предназначен - чтоб создавать интерфейс.

Comment: Можно, но незачем :) Вы правы - следует перейти на Unity UI (и присмотреться к Elements)